# Как добавить описание к изображениям в слайдере?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить описание к картинкам используя *голый* JS?
Папка с картинками находится в одной директории.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>
           <button id="prev"> &#10096; </button>
           <img src="./img/1.png" width="720px" height="480px" />
           <button id="next"> &#10097; </button>
       </div>
       <script src="js.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

```
 button {
    margin-top:240px;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
 }
 img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
 }
```

Не судите строго, если код корявый

```
    window.onload = function() {

    var images = ['img/2.png', 'img/3.png']

    var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
    var next = document.getElementById("next");
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var i = 0, r;

    prev.addEventListener("click", function() {move(-1)});
    next.addEventListener("click", function() {move(+1)});

    function move(r) {
        i += r;
        i >= images.length ? i = 0 : i;
        i < 0 ? i = images.length -1 : i;
        img[0].src = images[i];


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в принципе продублировал slider и чуть чуть модифицировал =>

Как проверите отпишитесь - как вам такое решение

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var images = ['slider/pic1.jpg', 'slider/pic2.jpg', 'slider/pic3.jpg']
  var mass = ['description1', 'description2', 'description3']

  var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
  var next = document.getElementById("next");
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var par = document.querySelector(".description p");
  var i = 0,
    b = 0,
    r;

  prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
    move(-1)
  });
  next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    move(+1)
  });

  function move(r) {
    i += r;
    b += r;
    i >= images.length ? i = 0 : i;
    b >= mass.length ? b = 0 : b;
    i < 0 ? i = images.length - 1 : i;
    b < 0 ? b = mass.length - 1 : b;
    img[0].src = images[i];
    par.textContent = mass[i];

  }

}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 820px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slider img {
  width: 720px;
  height: 480px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  margin-top: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 720px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
}

.description p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <button id="prev"> &#10096; </button>
  <img src="slider/pic1.jpg">
  <button id="next"> &#10097; </button>

  <div class="description">
    <p>description1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем варианте мне не понятно, как правильно вставить текст, могли бы, пожалуйста, прокомментировать?

Comment: @FlyAway а в js же есть ещё один массив - ниже того в котором ссылка на изображения в нём все текста

Comment: Доперло. Спасибо)